# Internal Email / Daily News Feed

Tags: email, rss, web, feed-reader

My company is currently looking for a software that will help keep everyone on the same page and limit email communication to one email a day, other that high importance emails.

**The Basic Idea of the System**

Certain people could log into the system and create a post or they could send/forward an email to a particular inbox. The creation of the post would be similar to WordPress (which may be the solution im just not sure how). It could be text, images, or a video, just like a regular blog post. The key to this too is there needs to be a way to extract contents from a forwarded email, so the 100+ emails are company is forwarded about new products, could be forwarded to this system.

Then at the end of the day one email would be generated and sent to the entire recipients list. The email that would be sent would be simple text, maybe a small thumbnail. It would only show the headline of the post and then a button to view more. The view more would take you to the post.

These generated messages need to be archivable and searchable later on, which could be the post itself.

There also needs to be a way for people to leave comments as well.

I recognize I have described something very similar to WordPress but there are crucial pieces missing that I cannot find a plugin that will do it. Management has decided that this is important but not important enough for programming to build. Are there any software tools that can help?